# SignalR client with multiple connections

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I have multiple SignalR 'services' running and only one UI to access them.

How can I make the client js to talk to multiple connections with different Url? Because it seems I can only specify one url per $.connection.hub, and I can't use multiple 'signalr/hubs' client scripts.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

$.connection.hub is created in the /signalr/hubs inclusion.

At the end of the file it essentially does:

```
$.connection.hub = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
```

To create the hub proxy you do:

```
var myHub = $.connection.hub.createHubProxy('myHub');
```

Simple example for multiple connections:

```
var connection1 = $.hubConnection("http://www.myfirstendpoint.com");
var connection2 = $.hubConnection("http://www.mysecondendpoint.com");

var myCon1Hub = connection1.createHubProxy('myCon1Hub');
var myCon2Hub = connection2.createHubProxy('myCon2Hub');

myCon1Hub.client.foo = function() { ... Whatever you want ... };
myCon2Hub.client.foo = function() { ... Whatever you want ... };

connection1.start();
connection2.start();
```

Comment: Beware that browsers have a limited number of concurrent connections per domain. So if you open a few tabs your page might stop loading.

Comment: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs-%28No-Proxy%29 provides more documentation on creating your own `hubConnection`s

Comment: This is important information that should be included as part of the SignalR documentation.  I would suggest adding it to the [ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide - JavaScript Client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)

Comment: @dfowler  With respect to concurrent connections, does that apply to Web Socket connections or just AJAX?  I mean, if you can guarantee Web Sockets will be used by SignalR do you have to worry about this?

Comment: Taylor, I think there are some problems with your sample code.  After you create myCon1Hub and myCon2Hub the way to attach functions is:  `myCon1Hub.on('foo', function() ( ... };`

Comment: Is this solution also possible with auto generated proxies?

Comment: You can definitely do this with auto-generated proxies. You'd use $.connection.hub as one of your connections and then you'd do what I did above $.connection.hub.createHubProxy(....) for your second.

Answer (score 6):

My solution for such occasions:

```
var SignalRHelpers = function () {
  var _connectionDeferred;

  var subscribeToConnectionStart = function (callback) {
    if (!_connectionDeferred)   // start connection if not yet initialized
        _connectionDeferred = $.connection.hub.start();

    if ($.connection.hub.state == $.connection.connectionState.connected && callback) {
        // already connected
        callback();
    } else if (callback) {
        // register handler
        _connectionDeferred.done(callback);
    }
  };

  return {
    SubscribeToConnectionStart: subscribeToConnectionStart
  };
}();
```

It internally stores the promise object from start() and attaches handlers as needed.

Basically you just call SignalRHelpers.SubscribeToConnectionStart every time you need to connect. For example

```
SignalRHelpers.SubscribeToConnectionStart(function(){
    someHub.server.executeSomething();
});
```

Comment: This resolved a very mystical problem I was having in my SPA, where I'd have to refresh the page for SignalR to work while I was on the view with SignalR, it simply wouldn't work if I navigated to it. But using SubscribeToConnectionStart instead of plain $.connection.hub.start()