# SignalR with multiple event handlers per event

Tags: javascript, signalr

In C# i would hook many handlers to an event like so:

```
event += firstEventHandler;
event += secondEventHandler;
```

but JavaScript with SignalR we write:

```
$.connection.someHubName.client.someEventName = function (item) {
    console.log("someMessage", item);
};
```

I have created a wrapper that looks a little like this:

```
var signalRClient = {
    start: function (callback) {
        $.connection.hub.url = ajaxHttp + "/signalr";
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        if ($.connection.hub && $.connection.hub.state === $.signalR.connectionState.disconnected) {
            $.connection.hub.start({ jsonp: true, withCredentials: true, transport: ['webSockets', 'longPolling'] }).done(callback);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    },
    connection: $.connection
}
```

That i can call in this way:

```
signalRClient.connection.somehub.client.someEvent = function (item) {
    console.log("someMessage", item);
};

signalRClient.start(function () { 
    signalRClient.connection.somehub.server.subscribe(someId);
});
```

but i if i run the signalRClient in more than one view (on the same rendered page) it can only assign one function to one event. I want to be able to assign many functions to one event.

I have read:
[connect to signalr hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671626/connect-to-signalr-hub) and [SignalR client with multiple connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468662/signalr-client-with-multiple-connections) ++

But i don't think it's a good idea to create many connections to the same hub for this purpose. I would also try to avoid creating my SignalR code in a layout and make all views dependent on this.

Is there a simple solution available so that i can hook on many events handlers to the `$.connection.somehub.client.event` ?

Comment: you have all these event handlers as functions correct? then it's simple, `someEvent = function (item) { eventOne(item); eventTwo(item); eventThree(item); }`

Comment: "I would also try to avoid creating my SignalR code in a layout and make all views dependent on this." - this is the reason why i don't want to do what you are explaining... This is also why signalRClient is reusable...

Comment: `"I would also try to avoid creating my SignalR code in a layout and make all views dependent on this"` I don't understand this. Can you be more clear. To make all views dependent on this then this must be part of layout.. if you dont want to code in layout code it in a js file and put reference in layout.

Comment: Since you already have a wrapper add another property called events and keep it as an array. you can push as many functions as you want into this array and in your function `$.connection.somehub.client.event =function (){...` you can loop the array and execute each function.

Comment: Rephrased: "I don't want my views to be dependent on JavaScript in Layout.." in our solution we switch Layoutfiles from time to time, and if i had this in the layoutfiles i would have to have the reference in all of them. I want the views i create to be self-sustaining. I don't want eventOne, eventTwo and eventThree to know about each other or called from the same place :)

Comment: I could have an array, but then the signalRClient would have to know about all of the events and hubs. Which it should not. signalRClient is a general wrapper.. not a specific one, and should be able to be reused in any application, regardless of hubs and events...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After trying many different things i managed to use the .on( command properly.. it is done like this:

```
signalRClient.connection.somehub.on("someevent", function(item) {
    console.log(item);
});

signalRClient.connection.somehub.on("someevent", function (item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

This will provide two lines in the console for each event.

Comment: This is good.  The SignalR documentation doesn't show this.  http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Comment: It acutally does, but it's in a rather hidden way. If you check out the "Without the generated proxy" header it creates the hubproxy and adds an .on( event. This is what took me so long to understand, that i could use this with strongly typed version "With the generated proxy" mixing them is not a problem it seems :)

Comment: @Bjørn ... could you clarify what 'somehub' is... I assume it is the name of the hub you are connecting to but I don't seem to have an object with that name in my connection.

Comment: It's quite some time since i did this, but from memory it's the generated proxy you'd be using. The event name is used in the same way here: $.connection.someHubName.client.someEventName, if you have not defined this, i believe you can do var someHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('someHub') documentation should be straight forward from this part:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#how-to-get-a-proxy-for-a-hub-class